# How to divert traffic based on hostname using HAProxy?

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, load-balancing, hostname, haproxy

I've had some initial success with HAProxy setting up a bunch of app servers listening on various other ports.

I now have another webserver listening on one port, and i'd like to what changes to make to my config to flow traffic by hostname as well.

The following is the current setup, assuming:

- my apache webserver is running at examplecom:8001
- my bunch of app servers 0.0.0.0:8081, 0.0.0.0:8082 , 0.0.0.0:8083

> ```
> global
>   log 127.0.0.1 local0
>   log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice
>   maxconn 4096
>   debug
>   #quiet
>   #user haproxy
>   #group haproxy
>
> defaults
>   log global
>   mode  http
>   option  httplog
>   option  dontlognull
>   retries 3
>   redispatch
>   maxconn 2000
>   contimeout  5000
>   clitimeout  50000
>   srvtimeout  50000
>
> listen appservers 0.0.0.0:80
>   mode http
>   balance roundrobin
>   option httpclose
>   option forwardfor
>   #option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
>   server  inst1 0.0.0.0:8081 cookie server01 check inter 2000 fall  3
>   server  inst2 0.0.0.0:8082 cookie server02 check inter 2000 fall  3
>   server  inst3 0.0.0.0:8083 cookie server01 check inter 2000 fall  3
>   server  inst4 0.0.0.0:8084 cookie server02 check inter 2000 fall  3
>   capture cookie vgnvisitor= len 32
> ```

(any other comments on the ^ setup are welcome.)

Now I'd like to continue the same above, but in addition in case - if the hostname is myspecialtopleveldomain<dot>com, then would like to flow traffic to example<dot>com:8001

~B

Comment: It is possible to send requests to different servers based on the hostname using frontend & backend configuration. Your question is a little confusing though, you mention example.com:8001, but it's not in the config anywhere. Is that the destination for requests to myspecialtopleveldomain.com on port 80? Perhaps you can give a few sample URLs that users would enter and where you want those URLs to be sent by haproxy.

Answer (score 26):

Here is an example:

```
frontend http
        bind 0.0.0.0:80
        default_backend www
        # NAT static host names and static paths in other hostnames to a different backend
        acl host_static hdr_beg(host) -i static.
        acl url_static  path_beg         /static
        use_backend static if host_static or url_static

backend www
        balance roundrobin
        server  qa1 10.177.1.81:80
        server  qa2 10.177.1.45:80

backend static
        balance roundrobin
        server  media1 10.177.0.86:80
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample config, you've just helped me finalise our load-balancer config :)